# expression - unrecognized method

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

How can I do the following in linq to entities for entity framework::

```
public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> IsOk<T>(long? entityId)
{
  return x => (!entityId.HasValue || entityId.Value == x.GetEntityId());
 }
```

The `x.GetEntityId()` returns an exception since it doesn't recognize the method.

Comment: not an answer, but since when did 'IsOK' cut it as a method name!

Comment: @Mitch Wheat: It is just an example.

Comment: @Naor; Have you considered the possibilty that you might be trying to make things too complicated? just a thought....

Comment: @Mitch Wheat: can you explain?

Comment: What kind of thing do you expect the type parameter T to be?

Comment: @John K, @zespri: T can be any class that represent POCO entity. for this example, GetEntityId always returns -1. I have to use the GetEntityId method.

Comment: "I have to use the GetEntityId method." You can't unless you do the filtering client-side, as per Aliostad's answer.

Comment: @zespri : I don't mind changing it so it will do the same (it returns a number).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot - your database cannot run `GetEntityId()` (since it does not understand it) hence your Linq provider cannot translate it.

---

## UPDATE

So how can you solve it:

- Id must be a property on the entity hence mapped to a column in the database. This way it can be easily used in an expression
- If Id is calculated (there is logic in `GetEntityId()`) then this needs to be done at the client: return all rows and do the filtering in C# subsequently. Of course it is needless to say what it is gonna do to your performance.

Comment: So how can I solve it? what options do I have? Is this something relate to ExpressionTree?

Comment: I mapped the property to the db.

Answer (score 1):

I'll suggest your type parameter be restricted to a custom interface like `IMyExpectation` which contains

```
interface IMyExpectation {
     int GetEntityId();
}
```

And then constrain your method's type parameter to that interface. (Now this will compile as far as the `GetEntityId` method goes.)

```
public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> IsOk<T>(long? entityId) 
       where T: IMyExpectation // << restrict the type to what is needed
{
  return new Func<T, bool>(
        x => !entityId.HasValue || entityId.Value == x.GetEntityId() 
  );
}
```

Then on the entity framework classes implement that interface where you need it, but on a `partial` part of the class in a separate file so the model doesn't obliterate your custom code whenever the model is regenerated. e.g.

**On your EF model entities**
*Note: This is subject to  [Aliostad's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891202/expression-unrecognized-method/5891213#5891213).*

```
public partial class Customer : IMyExpectation { //...

public partial class Invoice : IMyExpectation { //....

// etc
```

**Or, on your POCOs**
*Note: This should work fine if unencumbered by EF classes*

```
public class CustomerPoco: IMyExpectation { //...

public class InvoicePoco : IMyExpectation { //...
```

Now your entities and classes (and whatever you implemented  'IMyExpectation' on) are all expressing themselves just as your original method wants.
Finally your method will understand any of these things you've implemented the interface on, and therefore they are all candidates to be passed to the method via its type parameter.

If yours is the right scenario for this answer, then that should wrap things up nicely.

Comment: @John K: It won't help since the db don't know what is GetEntityId().

Comment: I also added a where T ... am writing on the fly though. Is your logic able to access the `ClassName` class that has the GetEntityId() method on it?

Comment: In the end I took a shot and suggested an interface. Because I'm unsure I went the right direction for your needs, if this answer is way off base I'll delete it as noise.

Comment: @John K: Yes, I think there are two problems here. First his code won't compile because GetEntityId method does not exist on just any type, and this is what you are trying to help with. Second, when it compiles it won't run, because EntityFramework won't be able to translate the method into a store command, and this is what Aliostad is trying to help with.

Comment: Updated the answer with POCOs.

Comment: @John K: this line "x => !entityId.HasValue || entityId.Value == x.GetEntityId()" will throw an exception that GetEntityId is incorrect method. the SQL SERVER doesn't know what is "GetEntityId".

Comment: Yes, in that case you're going to have to follow Aliostad's answer and look for a solution there. My answer only addresses strong typing of the type parameter argument.